# Why Google analytics shows self referral

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

One of my client has website with sub domain. After Google has launched universal analytics, i started seeing  own domain and sub-domains as referral traffic!

I already implemented base URL in script:

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'domain.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');

The same code has been inserted in sub-domain too!

The issue is still not resolved.

Any feedback?

Comment: technically subdomains are different domains (at least how google sees them).  You can either setup adwords rules to strip out this traffic (from your own subdomains) or need to tag your outbound links, or add some javascript to override the referrer in tracking to null.

Comment: You may need to add your domains to a referral exclusion list. You can find more info here: http://www.whymeasurethat.com/2013/05/10/universal-analytics-how-to-do-cross-domain-tracking/

Comment: Actually i already added my domains into referral exclusion list but no change in data!

Comment: Google's data does not retroactively change it is read-only. From the point of change onwards there should be a noticeable difference. Have you checked to make sure your default site is not a subdomain? Administration›Property Settings›Property Settings [Default URL]